# WebSocket Handshake Error with AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, java-websocket

I'm running a Java server (Jetty, to be specific) on an AWS EC2 instance using WebSocket to connect to a client's browser. When I do this locally (hosting the server on my computer, not AWS), it runs fine. However, when I move the code to an EC2 instance, I get the following error message on the **client-side**:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://Elastic_IP:8080/?username=name_of_user' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500`

I made sure that the EC2 instance will accept traffic on port 8080.

On the **server-side**, I'm getting many `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when the connection is attempted. I do not get these error when I run it locally. Perhaps there's an issue when I'm compiling on the EC2 instance, however it does compile without error. I'm compiling and running the code using Eclipse locally, but I'm compiling and running the code on EC2 by hand (`javac` with lots of classpaths). It's likely that I made an error when compiling by hand, but I'm not sure what the error could be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
After a little trouble-shooting on my own, I realized that `JSON.ParseException` was the source of issue. After I removed all calls to this class from the server code, the handshake completed and I was able to establish a connection between the server and the client. 
However, I am now running into the following error when I receive a message from the client:

```
WARN:MyWebSocketHandler:qtp990368553-16: Unhandled Error (closing connection) 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot call method public void 
MyWebSocketHandler#onMessage(org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session, java.lang.String) with args:
[org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession, java.lang.String]
```

It seems that I defined the argument to be `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session`, but during runtime the argument is actually `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession`. Any ideas on how this is happening or which one (`Session` vs `WebSocketSession`) I should use? The only capability I need is to send strings between the server and the client.

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace, so that we can see which class, specifically, the JVM is complaining about?  Also, rather than using Eclipse to run your server code locally, could you try running it locally just as you would on the EC2 instance, so that your local environment is closer/more like the one that's on the EC2 instance?

Comment: @Castaglia I fixed the main issue for the handshake (I had to remove an import on the server code, but it does work on the local side with the import), but I'm hitting another road block. I updated the questions to reflect my misfortune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a possible solution to my problem. Through Eclipse, I can `Export` the Java project to a runnable jar ("packing" the libraries into the jar). Then running it with `java -jar <jar_filename>` will work on the server and function the same as on the local machine. However, I've notice some performance issues (slow start), so I do not think this is the *best* solution, however it is a solution.